# Generating Functions or Counting?

Tags: generating-functions

Alice has two bags. Each bag has $4$ slips of paper with the numbers $1$ through $4$ on them.

Betty also has two bags, each with $4$ slips of paper with positive integers on them. They decide to play a game whereby each girl pulls a slip from each of her own bags, records the sum of the numbers, then returns each slip to the bag it came from. The numbers in Betty's bags are not $1$ through $4$ in each bag, but the expected distribution of her sums is the same as Alice's. What are all eight numbers in Betty's bags?

---

Would a way to solve this problem be using generating functions? Counting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. Start by computing the frequency distribution of sums for Alice:

$$\begin{array}{rccc}
\text{sum}:&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
\text{frequency}:&1&2&3&4&3&2&1
\end{array}$$

Betty has the same distribution, and the slips of paper in her bags have positive integers written on them.

- Show that each of Betty’s bags must contain exactly one slip with the number $1$.
- Show that if each of Betty’s bags contained a slip with the number $2$, then her bags would be a copy of Alice’s which is not allowed. Conclude that one of Betty’s bags contains two slips numbered $2$, and the other contains no slips numbered $2$.

At this point we know that one of Betty’s bags contains a $1$ and no $2$s, and the other contains a $1$ and two $2$s, so we have totals of $2,3$, and $3$, and the smallest remaining number in either bag is a $3$.

- Show that in order to get the sum $4$ with frequency $3$, we must have two $3$s in one bag and one $3$ in the other. Which bag is which?
- Now complete the assignment of numbers to Betty’s bags.

Comment: Are the eight numbers $1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4$? $1, 2, 2, 3$ for one of the bags and $1, 3, 3, 4$ for the other?

Comment: @Regina: Not quite: you can’t get $8$ with those numbers, and you get frequencies of $5,4$, and $1$ for $5,6$, and $7$, when you should have $4,3$, and $2$. One of your numbers has to be changed, but only one.

Comment: Is it $1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5$?  I know it's the last number.

Comment: @Regina: Yes, assuming that you split it $1,2,2,3$ and $1,3,3,5$,

Comment: [+1] Thanks for taking your time to go over this problem with me!

Comment: @Regina: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Generating functions, I think.

The generating function for Alice’s outcomes is $g(x)=(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^2$. Can you find polynomials (one for each of Betty’s bags, which have $N$ and $M$ slips in them, respectively) $b_1(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}x^{n_i}$ and $b_2(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{M}x^{m_i}$ where $g(x)=b_1(x)\cdot b_2(x)$ and the sets $\{n_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{m_i\}_{i=1}^M$ are sets of positive integers that are different from $\{1,2,3,4\}$?